# postgresql while loop with declared vars

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have from outside timestamp range for example from '2022-04-01' to '2022-04-07' and i need go through each date from this range and execute SELECT query and expect to receive 7 rows in result. I tried next construction:

```
DO $$DECLARE 
_first_date timestamp := '2022-04-01';
_second_date timestamp := '2022-04-07';
BEGIN
WHILE _first_date<=_second_date LOOP
SELECT :_first_date, count(*) from my_table where date_column_in_my_table = :_first_date;
_first_date := _first_date + interval '1' day;
END LOOP;
END$$;
```

but i have syntax error at or near ":" on ':_first_date' line. Next i tried another test query:

```
DO $$DECLARE 
_first_date timestamp := '2022-04-01';
_second_date timestamp := '2022-04-07';
BEGIN
WHILE _first_date<=_second_date LOOP
select 'test_text';
_first_date := _first_date + interval '1' day;
END LOOP;
END$$;
```

but now i have:
'ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 6 at SQL statement',
which seems to say that SELECT query does not work with this conditions.

Can I somehow get the desired result in the result set:

```
2022-04-01, 5
2022-04-02, 12
2022-04-03, 6
2022-04-04, 3
2022-04-05, 4
2022-04-06, 11
2022-04-07, 0
```

?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

A `DO` block can't return a result. But there is no need to use a loop or PL/pgSQL for this. You can use `generate_series()` to generate the list of dates and then join that to your table. If you make that an outer join, you also get a zero count for dates that don't exist in your table:

```
select g.dt::date, count(t.date_column_in_my_table) 
from generate_series(date '2022-04-01', 
                     date '2022-04-07', 
                     interval '1 day') as g(dt)
  left join my_table t on t.date_column_in_my_table := g.dt::date
group by g.dt::date
```

The cast `g.dt::date` is necessary because `generate_series()` always returns a timestamp, even if the parameters are all dates.